# Can someone easily explain Artin's conjecture on primitive roots?

Tags: elementary-number-theory, conjectures, primitive-roots

*Wikipedia (1):
In number theory, Artin's conjecture on primitive roots states that a given integer a that is neither a perfect square nor −1 is a primitive root modulo infinitely many primes p.*

and

*Wikipedia(2): In modular arithmetic, a branch of number theory, a number g is a primitive root modulo n if every number a coprime to n is congruent to a power of g modulo n.*

These two definitions seem to be enough to understand Artin´s conjecture in its formulation, however, I am facing some difficulties, so if someone can explain this conjecture very easily that would be nice.

Thanks.

Comment: What do you find confusing?  [Here](http://oeis.org/A001122) for instance is the list of primes for which $2$ is a primitive root.  Artin would tell us that this list is infinite, thought of course that is not known.  Easy to see that no perfect square can ever be a primitive root.

Comment: @lulu Is 3 in this list because, for example, $3|2^4-1$?

Comment: No.  $3$ is on the list because $2^1\not \equiv 1\pmod 3$ but $2^2\equiv 1 \pmod 3$.  Thus the order of $2\pmod 3$ is $3-1=2$.  Similarly the order of $2\pmod 5$ is $4$ so $2$ is also a primitive root $\pmod 5$.

Comment: @lulu Ah, so the exponents must be smaller than the base?

Comment: No...for any prime $p$ and any integer $a$ prime to $p$, we have $a^{p-1}\equiv 1 \pmod p$.  so you know that the order of $a\pmod p$ must be less than or equal to $p-1$.  With a little effort you can show that the order must be a divisor of $p-1$.  For a primitive root the order is exactly $p-1$.

Comment: @lulu Thank you, I understand more now, the facts you´re mentioning are Fermat´s and Euler´s theorems?

Comment: The claim that $a^{p-1}\equiv 1 \pmod p$ is the so-called [Little Fermat's Theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fermat%27s_little_theorem).  Euler generalized this to composite moduli.

Answer (score 1):

A base $a$ is a primitive root modulo a prime $p$ , if the smallest positive integer $k$ with $$a^k\equiv 1\bmod p$$ is equal to $p-1$ , the largest possible order. Artin's conjecture is that for every nonzero $a$ that is not $-1$ or a perfect square, there are infinite many primes $p$ doing the job.